# How to handle with dropdown menu on Phptravels.net website using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have some big problem with handle with dropdown menu on https://www.phptravels.net/ website.

I wrote this test, but it doesn't work and I don't have idea how to do it correctly.

```
public class HomePage {

    private Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"li_myaccount\"]/ul")
    private WebElement dropDownMenu;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"li_myaccount\"]/ul/li")
    private WebElement dropDownMenuOptions;

    public HomePage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(DriverManager.getWebDriver(), this);
    }

    public void clickOnMyAccountDropMenuAndSelectOption(String option) {
        WaitForElement.waitUntilElementIsVisible(dropDownMenu);
        dropDownMenu.click();

        List<WebElement> options = DriverManager.getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"li_myaccount\"]/ul/li"));

        for(WebElement o: options) {
            if(o.getText().equals(option)) {
                o.click();
                return;
            }
        }   
    }

    public void clickOnLoginLink() {
        WaitForElement.waitUntilElementIsClickable(loginLink);
        loginLink.click();
        logger.info("Clicked on Login link");
    }
}
```

My question is that how should I change clickOnMyAccountDropMenuAndSelectOption method to make test correct? Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you describe what output you are getting?  Where/what is the error; have you verified your FindBy's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class HomePage {

  private Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();

  @FindBy(xpath = "//nav//*[@id='li_myaccount']/a")
  private WebElement dropDownMenu;

  @FindBy(xpath = "//nav//*[@id='li_myaccount']/ul/li/a")
  private WebElement dropDownMenuOptions;

  public HomePage() {
    PageFactory.initElements(DriverManager.getWebDriver(), this);
  }

  public void clickOnMyAccountDropMenuAndSelectOption(String option) {
    WaitForElement.waitUntilElementIsVisible(dropDownMenu);
    dropDownMenu.click();

    Thread.sleep(2000); // wait 2 seconds until dropdown loads
    List<WebElement> options = DriverManager.getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//nav//*[@id='li_myaccount']/ul/li/a"));

    for(WebElement o: options) {
      if(o.getText().equals(option)) {
        o.click();
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  public void clickOnLoginLink() {
    WaitForElement.waitUntilElementIsClickable(loginLink);
    loginLink.click();
    logger.info("Clicked on Login link");
  }
}
```

Your `xPaths` were not correct. I have fixed them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some of the **locators** :

It's always a good practice to use **css selector** over **xpath**.

For this :

```
  @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"li_myaccount\"]/ul")
   private WebElement dropDownMenu;
```

Use this :

```
@FindBy(css= "li#li_myaccount>a[aria-expanded]")
private WebElement dropDownMenu;
```

For this :

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"li_myaccount\"]/ul/li")
private WebElement dropDownMenuOptions;
```

Use this :

```
@FindBy(css= "div#collapse ul.navbar-right li#li_myaccount li>a")
private WebElement dropDownMenuOptions;
```

And in this method use it like :

```
List<WebElement> options = DriverManager.getWebDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector("div#collapse ul.navbar-right li#li_myaccount li>a"));

for(WebElement o: options) {
  if(o.getText().trim().contains("Login")) {
                o.click();
            }
        }
```